# How to get ACF field value form custom taxonomy inside foreach?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field with 'domain_url' id  to  add  field  in my taxonomy using the following code:

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_6294fa89c564b',
    'title' => 'Domain url Field',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_629504c3cdd67',
            'label' => 'domain url',
            'name' => 'domain_url',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'taxonomy',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'news_source',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    
));
```

And I want to get the value inside the categories foreach, I tried this code but it didn't give a result

```
  <?php
   $args = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'news_source',
              
           );

   $cats = get_categories($args);

   foreach($cats as $cat) {
?>
        Name:   <?php echo $cat->name; ?>  > 
        Domain:    <?php echo get_field('domain_url' ); ?> <br/> 
           
  
      
<?php
   }
?>

Is the problem in the code? Or does the extension not support it?
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an argument in your `get_field()`. You need to add an arg for the term or term object.

```
  <?php
   $args = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'news_source',
              
           );

   $cats = get_categories($args);

   foreach($cats as $cat) {
?>
        Name:   <?php echo $cat->name; ?>  > 
        Domain:    <?php echo get_field('domain_url', $cat ); ?> <br/> // Put the term in here.
           
  
      
<?php
   }
?>
```

In this case you may need an extra query, or to use the term string plus the term ID in a string.

[This ACF documentation article](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/) shows some different methods of retrieving tax term fields as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already tried this method, but it didn't give any result..
When I use `var_dump( get_field('domain_url', "1368" ));` for exemple , the result is `NULL`

Comment: i found the solution in using 
`<?php echo get_field('domain_url', 'term_' . $category->term_id  ); ?>`